# Is there a way to test that all my policies have been added in AddAuthorization in .Net Core 3.1?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .Net Core 3.1 API with multiple policies because I need different permissions for every route. I add my policies this way:

```
services
.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
       foreach (var policy in policyParams)
       {
           options.AddPolicy(policy);
       }
    });
```

where `options.AddPolicy(policy)` does that

```
public static void AddPolicy(this AuthorizationOptions authorizationOptions, PolicyParams policyParams)
        {
            authorizationOptions.AddPolicy(policyParams.Name, p => ...
        }
```

I would like to write some test to make sure that all my policies are added. I tried this way, but the execution never goes inside the `AddAuthorization` to verify the condition in the loop:

```
var sut = Substitute.ForPartsOf<ServiceCollection>();
sut.Received(1).AddAuthorization(options =>
{
     foreach (var policy in policyParams)
     {
          options.GetPolicy(policy.Name).Should().NotBeNull();
     }
});
```

Is there a way to verify that all my policies have been added?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to access the registed policy as below:

Inside ConfigureServices Method：

```
services.AddAuthorization(x => {
                var policy = x.GetPolicy("Policy1");
                .....
                x.AddPolicy("Policy1", policy => policy.RequireRole("Admin"));
                });
```

[image]

Otside ConfigureServices Method:

```
var policy=serviceprovider.GetService<IAuthorizationPolicyProvider>().GetPolicyAsync(policyname).Result;
```

[image]

Comment: Inside the ```AddAuthorization``` doesn't work when you do testing. However, the second way works. You should change your answer so that only the second way of doing thing is shown.